# Email Alerts (batch jobs) going to users after canceled

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

Is there a table or a class that shows all emails for all batch jobs? We have users getting emails for jobs that are canceled.

Comment: Do the batch jobs them serves send emails, or are the Emails the alerts sent on completion by AX? If the latter look in BatchJobAlerts table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To agree with Jan, there is no email log.

Even further, jobs that are canceled should not continue to send emails...so it sounds like the job isn't actually canceled.

To find alerts setup by the user, in the AOT go to `Tables\BatchJobAlerts`.  There you can see things like user and email.  The `BatchJobId` field is a recId that can be looked up against `Tables\BatchJob` in the recId field.  This will tell you the offending batch jobs.

Comment: All I see are createdBy, recVersion, RecId

Comment: Ah, you will have to make the fields visible or look directly in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no email log.

You will have to manually click the Alerts button on the waiting batch jobs (as set up in the `BatchJobAlerts` table).

Comment: Yeah, this job/alert is not in this table at all but somehow the server is still sending email to the users.